# VBA Copy non-blank cells in EACH worksheet to existing worksheet

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, nested-loops, worksheet

I don't even know where to start so I don't have any example code. I am thinking that I need a nested loop but that is what throws me off. I look forward to learning from everyone.

Here is what I'd like to do:

1. Begin with the worksheet named "John" and loop through each worksheet to the right.
2. On each worksheet, if a cell in column L is not blank, copy cell F and cell L for that row.
3. Append all of the copied cells to the worksheet "Notes". Paste the data from F on each sheet to column A and paste the corresponding data from L in column B. Add the copied data from each worksheet to the end of the data in "Notes".

I really appreciate any help, thanks!!

**UPDATE**
Based on Alter's great help and suggestions, this is what I have and it works perfectly. Thanks Alter!

```
    Sub test()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim notes_ws As Worksheet
        Dim row
        Dim lastrow
        Dim notes_nextrow

        'find the worksheet called notes
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Notes" Then
                Set notes_ws = ws
            End If
        Next ws

        'get the nextrow to print to
        notes_nextrow = notes_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

        'loop through other worksheets
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            'ignore the notes worksheet
            If ws.Name <> "Notes" And ws.Index > Sheets("John").Index Then
                'find lastrow
                lastrow = ws.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                For row = 1 To lastrow
                    'if the cell is not empty
                    If IsEmpty(ws.Range("L" & row)) = False Then
                        notes_ws.Range("A" & notes_nextrow).Value = ws.Range("F" & row).Value
                        notes_ws.Range("B" & notes_nextrow).Value = ws.Range("L" & row).Value
                        notes_nextrow = notes_nextrow + 1
                    End If
                Next row
            End If
        Next ws
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you post any code that you've attempted please

Comment: Which specific part are you having a problem with? Worksheets have an `Index` property which tells you their position in the workbook, so you can loop from John's `Index`+1 to `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets.Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested loop indeed, you can use the code below as a basis for what you want to do

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim notes_ws As Worksheet
    Dim row
    Dim lastrow
    Dim notes_nextrow

    'find the worksheet called notes
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.name = "Notes" Then
            Set notes_ws = ws
        End If
    Next ws

    'get the nextrow to print to
    notes_nextrow = notes_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

    'loop through other worksheets
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'ignore the notes worksheet
        If ws.name <> "Notes" Then
            'find lastrow
            lastrow = ws.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            For row = 1 To lastrow
                'if the cell is not empty
                If IsEmpty(ws.Range("L" & row)) = False Then
                    notes_ws.Range("A" & notes_nextrow).Value = ws.Range("L" & row).Value
                    notes_nextrow = notes_nextrow + 1
                End If
            Next row
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Alter, this is definitely on the right track! Thank you for the notes. I am still learning how loops work and I don't fully understand how the "For each" and the "For" statements work. I tested this and it does the first step of finding all of the non-blanks on each sheet and puts them on the "Notes" sheet. But, I need to match up the data in column F for any non-blank cell in column L and put it in Row A in the "Notes" sheet. I think I can switch the notes range to ("B" & notes_nextrow) but how do I get column F?

Comment: I should also add that I'd like to start the loop with the "John" worksheet and go through all worksheets to the right. Is this possible?

Comment: same idea, ws.Range("F" & row).value will get the value from column F. You can modify the line that copies the column L into column A so that it copies column F into column B

Comment: As for the "To the right" solution, sheet's are arranged by their index property. What you have to the is find the value of John.index, and then make sure you only loop through sheets that have a higher index.